# Вызывать каждый элемент div отдельно по кнопке JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Привет. Есть такая проблема. Есть например три item. Одинаковые по структуре, но у каждого свой текст внутри дива. А также для каждого отдельная кнопка для вызова div. Нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, нужный див, выводился попапом с colorbox. 
Если просто по клику, обращаться к диву, то вызываются все одновременно, так как классы одинаковые.

Поэтому я написал такой код:

```
    (function ($) {
  $('p.programma').click(function(){
    var output = $('.programma-item').html();
    $.colorbox({html:output});
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Он работает. Но метод html() вызывает только первый элемент массива.

Как сделать чтобы, по нажатию на кнопку, вызывался только относящийся к этому диву див?

Comment: добавь пример разметки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function ($) {
  $('p.programma').click(function(){
    var index = $('p.programma').index(this);
    var output = $('.programma-item').eq(index).html();
    $.colorbox({html:output});
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Супер! спасибо. Логически я так и мыслил, но не мог записать это в виде кода.

Comment: @AlexSorokin На здоровье. Успехов!